# ggplot - multiple boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to create boxplots with this dataset faceting by factor mix (3 boxplots combined):

```
daf <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xxYjmdgD", header=T, sep="\t")
```

This is what the sample looks like:

```
                                            ia mix   Rs
1                                    Fluazinam   1 0.62
2                                    Fluazinam   1 0.76
3                                    Fluazinam   1 0.76
4                                    Fluazinam   1 0.52
5                                    Fluazinam   1 0.56
6                                    Fluazinam   1 0.20
7                                    Fluazinam   1 0.98
235 Carbendazim+Cresoxim-Metílico+Tebuconazole   3 0.65
236 Carbendazim+Cresoxim-Metílico+Tebuconazole   3 0.28
237 Carbendazim+Cresoxim-Metílico+Tebuconazole   3 0.41
```

These are my failed attempts!

```
library(ggplot2) 

qplot( Rs, ia, data=daf) + 
  facet_grid(mix ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free", labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

» When I add the `qplot( Rs, ia, data=daf, geom="boxplot")`
  It simply appear a line, not the box.

```
ggplot(data=daf, aes(x=ia, y=Rs))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "black", outlier.size = 2)  +  
  coord_flip() +  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.25))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", shape = 4, size = 3, colour = "blue") +
  facet_grid(mix ~. , scales = "free", space="free", labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

» It repeats every "ia" level into each "mix" level

```
ggplot(data=daf, aes(x=ia, y=Rs))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "black", outlier.size = 2)  +  
  layer(data = a, mapping = aes(x = ia, y= 0, label=a$Rs.median),
        geom = "text", color="NavyBlue", size=3.5) +
  coord_flip() +  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.25))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", shape = 4, size = 3, colour = "blue")
```

[image]

Finally I'd like a combination of the three plots:

from the first plot, the facet.grid(without repeating "ia" variables), from the second one, the boxes, and from the third one the median values in the left inside margin, and if it could be possible, into each level of factor "mix", reordering the "ia" by median values...

Could someone help me with this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geom_boxplot` assumes the categorical variables are on the x-axis. `coord_flip` doesn't work in combination with `facet_grid` + `geom_boxplot`. One workaround is to rotate the text. You can export and rotate the image in another program (or figure out how to pull out the [`grid`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/00Index.html) object and rotate it).

```
a = ddply(daf, .(ia,mix), function(x) c(Rs=median(x$Rs, na.rm=TRUE)))

ggplot( data=daf, aes(x=ia, y=Rs) ) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~mix, scales="free_x") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", shape = 4, size = 3, colour = "blue") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle = 90, hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(strip.text=element_text(angle = 90, hjust=0.5)) +
  geom_text(data = a, mapping = aes(x = ia, y= 0.02, label=round(Rs,2)),
        color="NavyBlue", size=3.5, angle=90, hjust=1) +
  ylim(-0.03,1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add `vjust=0.5` to the x-axis labels so they'll be centered below the tick marks. Also, you can rotate the x-axis title by 90 degrees so that it will be in the desired orientation once the entire plot is rotated.

Comment: @kdauria: I tried your code with ggplot2 2.1.0 but getting `Error in layer(data = a, mapping = aes(x = ia, y = 0.02, label = round(Rs,  : 
  unused arguments (color = "NavyBlue", size = 3.5, angle = 90, hjust = 1, scale = "free_x")`. 
If I only used `layer(data = a, mapping = aes(x = ia, y= 0.02, label=round(Rs,2)), geom = "text"`, a different error occurred `Error: Attempted to create layer with no position.`
Any idea what went wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know why I used `layer` before. I got the same error on ggplot 2.0.0. I updated the answer so that it works on ggplot 2.0.0. If it doesn't work for you, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I found https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance and thought I'd make an alternative answer.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("lionel-/ggstance")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
daf <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xxYjmdgD", header=T, sep="\t")

library(dplyr)
a = daf %>% 
  group_by(ia, mix) %>%
  summarize(Rs=mean(Rs))

ggplot(daf, aes(x=Rs, y=ia)) +
  geom_boxploth() +
  geom_point(data=a, shape = 4, size = 3, colour = "blue") +
  geom_text(data = a, mapping = aes(y = ia, x=0, label=round(Rs,2)),
            color="NavyBlue", size=3.5, hjust=0) +
  facet_grid(mix~., scales="free_y")
```

[image]